# Javascript Dateformat Regular expression Understanding Syntax

Tags: javascript, regex

I came across a Javascript runtime error that was being thrown by a regular expression. The regular expression validates the date format. Accepts (yyyy/mm/dd) rejects(mm/dd/yyyy) etc.... I have read multiple sites on javascript regular expressions

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re2.shtml
http://www.diveintojavascript.com/articles/javascript-regular-expressions
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

I have spent countless hours trying to figure out the error in this expression. However I can't find any documentation on some the syntax. Here is what I have so far, any help or pointing me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

```
^(?ni:(?=\d)((?'year'((1[6-9])|([2-9]\d))\d\d)(?'sep'[/])(?'month'0?[1-9]|1[012])\2(?'day'((?<!(\2((0?[2469])|11)\2))31)|(?<!\2(0?2)\2)(29|30)|((?<=((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)\2\3\2)29)|((0?[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8])))(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))?((?<time>((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(\x20[AP]M))|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2}))?)$
```

I have added spaces and questions. there are * at the beginning and end of all questions I have. If you could also tell me why this is causing a runtime error, that would be awesome as well!

```
^
(
    ?ni:    * What does ?ni: mean? Is it a holder of some sort?*
    (?=\d)  goes to the first digit?
    (
    (

        ?'year' *is this another holder/state? If so, why is it not, ?year:  ? *
        (
        (1[6-9])
        |
        ([2-9]\d)
        )
```

```
        \d\d  *consumes the next two digits?*
)
(?'sep'[/]) *puts the seprator into sep?*
(?'month'0?[1-9]|1[012]) 
\2 *no idea what this does. Does it go back to start of text?*
(   
    ?'day'  *no idea what this does*
    (
            (
                ?<! *no idea what this does*
        (
             \2     
         (
             (0?[2469])
             |
             11
             )
             \2  
        )
    )   
    31
    )
    |
    (?<!\2(0?2)\2) *no idea what this does*
        (29|30)
        |
        (
            (
                ?<=    *no idea what this does*
                (
                    (
                        1[6-9]|[2-9]\d
                    )
                    (
                        0[48]
                        |
                        [2468][048]
                        |
                        [13579][26]
                    )
                    |
                    (16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])
                    00
                )
                \2  *no idea what this does*
                \3  *no idea what this does*
                \2  *no idea what this does*
            )
            29
        )
        |
        (
            (0?[1-9])
            |
            (1\d)
            |
            (2[0-8])
        )
    )
    (
        ?:   
        (?=\x20\d)\x20   *why is this using \x20 instead of \s?*
        |
        $  *no idea what this does... Does this finish the expression?*
    )
)
?
(
    (
        ?
        <time> *no idea what this does*
        (
            (
                0?
                [1-9]
                |
                1[012]
            )
            (:[0-5]\d){0,2}
            (\x20[AP]M)
        )
        |
        (
            [01]\d
            |
            2[0-3]
        )
        (:[0-5]\d){1,2} *no idea what this does*
    )
)
?
```

)
$

Comment: Have you tried http://regexpal.com ?

Comment: Actually, where did you get the regex string, as it looks like it might be for .Net regex?

Comment: regexpal.com is great, but sadly I have been using other sites like it with no success.It's currently part of .net framework, however I'm kinda no idea difference between .netregex and javascript regex :(

Comment: There are differences between the syntax of the two to do with how you capture matches and use them. The `(?<time>someregex)` that you see in yours is a named capturing group match in .Net, but isn't valid in JavaScript.

Comment: So if I remove the (?<time>someregex) it will work?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's just what made me notice that it's a .Net regex. It looks overly complex for what you are trying to achieve. I would go with something closer to Anirudh's answer. Or start from the beginning in regexpal and see what each step of creating your regex gives you back from a date as you do it.

Answer (score 1):

1>Get the dates with this regex

```
^(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})$
```

2> Validate month,year,day if the string matches with above regex!

```
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
parseInt(match[0],10);//year
parseInt(match[1],10);//month
parseInt(match[2],10);//day
```

Comment: I could do try other paths, however I would still like to know the answer to this question.

Comment: @A.sharif the regex you are trying is `.net` based..So, you have to remove those **named groups** because they are not supported by javascript but beware the above regex also uses **back references** so just remove the name part and the regex would just run fine

Comment: Ahh I'm sorry it's vb.net regex. It looked like javascript regex and I just presumed they were the same thing. Am I able to edit the tag of my post?

Comment: The expression is in the HTML, which is passed to a ScriptResource.axd  which has a javascript function, which throws the error.